# Can you disable network interfaces from the command line in Windows Server 2003?

Tags: networking, windows-server-2003, command-line-interface

Was wondering if it was possible to disable network interfaces from the command line in Windows Server 2003? If so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
netsh interface set interface name = "interface name" admin = disable
```